# Angular HTTP Client not showing error Details located in Response object

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am using the following code below to record an error message with a Service:

```
[... snip ...]


  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }



adminLogin(username, password): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
    let tokenResp = {};

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), { observe: 'response' })
      .map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");
        let t = JWT(token);
        return t;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

[... snip ...]
```

When looking at the Chrome Network tab (after executing a POST), I see the following in the network as part of the `Response`:

> {"timestamp":1518704916793,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication
>   Failed: Bad credentials","path":"/login"}

I am trying to get **Unauthorized** and **"Authentication Failed: Bad credentials** to be displayed as part of the error message; however, I am not seeing how this can be accessed with the `Response` object.

How can one access this information?

TIA

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the information. I changed the calling function as follows:

```
onSubmit(userForm: NgForm) {

    console.log(userForm);

    console.log(" getting ready to go call the service ");
    let sendUser = userForm.value.username;
    let sendPassword = userForm.value.passwordconf;

    console.log(" values for id and password " +
      sendUser + " ----- " + sendPassword);

    this.authService.adminLogin(sendUser, sendPassword).subscribe((response) => {
   [ ... snip ...]
    },
    ( error : any ) => {
     console.error( " --- function produced an error ");
     console.log( error );
     let errMsg = "HTTP Status : " + error.status + " MESSAGE " +  error.error.message; 
     console.error( errMsg );
    });
```

I used the following line:

> ```
>      let errMsg = "HTTP Status : " + error.status + " MESSAGE " +  error.error.message;
> ```

Because of what I saw when printing the "error" object:

[image]

**QUESTION:** Is this enough to do the error processing? It seems (according to the Network tab in Chrome) that the error type is `HttpErrorResponse` Does one need to make changes in anticipation of some other Error type popping up? That was the reason for using the "function" earlier.

Comment: You are doing way too much. Too many special cases. Too many type annotations. Too many checks. And in the process of doing too much, you are making false assumptions. Remove the `.catch` and everything that goes with it.

Comment: The error type is not Response, but HttpResponse if you are using HttpClient. So no need to call.json on the body. See here https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Comment: @David - so should the error be collected in the Service or with the Component?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad - thanks for the tip. I updated the message. Can you answer? TIA

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it. If you nee to do the same processing for all component calling the service, you may as well put it in the service